# How to compile f77 and f90 files together with gfortran

Tags: fortran, fortran90, gfortran, fortran77

I have a few dozens files with f77-functions and I would like to include them into my f90-program. How do I bring it altogether with gfortran? If I just try to

```
gfortran myprogram.f90
```

it complains for f77-code in the other files. As I understand, it would like to see all files put into definite standard (f77 of f90).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problems aren't F77 vs F90, they are fixed-form vs free-form.  You cannot combine both source formats into a single file.  You have two options:

1. Modify all of your source into one format (use free-form if you are going to do this), then compile your program as you are doing now.
2. Put all the fixed-form stuff in one bunch of source files and all the free-form stuff in another bunch, then do:

   ```
   gfortran -omyprogram free-form-stuff.f90 fixed-form-stuff.f
   ```

   This will compile each source file separately and then link them together into one executable.

Comment: @Ross: Indeed, it works, I'm surprised. The manpage says `-o outfile` and not `-ooutfile`.